# K&R, find longest line, same code but not working?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've just started to read K&R and on pages 32-33, there is a code that

> finds the longest line among the inputs.

I nearly completely copy-pasted the code given in the book, just added some comment lines to make the code more understandable for me. But it isn't working.

**Edit**: I'm sorry for bad questioning. It seems the program does not act properly when I press Ctrl + Z, in order to terminate it. No matter how many lines I type and how many times I press Ctrl + Z, it just does nothing.

The following is my version of the code:

```
/* Find the longest line among the giving inputs and print it */

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000            /* maximum input line length */

int getLine(char line[], int maxLine);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void) {
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here*/

    max = 0;

    /* getLine function takes all the input from user, returns it's size and equates it to the variable len
     * Then, len is compared whether it's greater than zero because if there's no input, no need to do any calculation
     * EDGE CASE
     */
    while ((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        /* If the length of input is larger than the previous max length, set max as the new length value and copy that input */
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line, EDGE CASE */
        printf("%s", longest);

    return 0;
}

/* Read a line into s, return length.
 * Since the input length is unknown, there should be a limit */
int getLine(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    /* The loop's first condition is whether the input length is below the limit. EDGE CASE
     * If it's not, omit the rest because it would cause a BUFFER OVERFLOW. Next, take the input as long as it's not an EOF command.
     * Finally, if the input is end of line, finish the loop, don' take it.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i++] = '\0'; // always put a '\0' character to a string array ending, so that the compiler knows it's a string.
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i = 0;

    // This loop is readily assigns all chars from the source array to the target array until it reaches the ending char.
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @acraig5075 Problem is "find the longest line among the lines typed by user". My problem is I nearly copy-pasted the same code given in the book with just a few comments but it isn't working.

Comment: If someone came to you with a problem, and just said "But it somehow isn't working", what would you do? :/

Comment: *How* isn't it working? For some example input, what is the expected and actual output? Perhaps you should take some time to [learn how to debug programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @unwind I'd advise him/her to debug the code but I'm using Eclipse and couldn't figure out how to debug my code yet.

Comment: @SaidBuyukarslan So you wouldn't try to understand the problem by asking *what happens?"

Comment: @unwind, The problem is code isn't catching the EOF sign when I press Ctrl + Z. I should've mentioned it on the first hand, I got it, sorry. Edited the original post, as well.

Comment: May not be related, but `getLine` is wrong. If you enter an empty line by just pressing the Enter key, the functions returns 2. Also the trailing `'\n'` is left at the end of the buffer, not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: CTRL+Z usually stops the process, but doesn't terminates it.  CTRL+D would be better to terminate the input flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's the error:

```
s[i++] = '\0'; // always put a '\0' character to a string array ending, so that the compiler knows it's a string.
```

This will cause it to terminate the string even for no input (when it got `EOF` directly), and since it increments `i` before returning it, `getLine()` will never return 0 and thus `main()` will never stop. Removing the `++` fixed it, for my simple test.

Also, the comment is misleading, the compiler doesn't know anything. The compiler is no longer around when the code runs; the in-memory format of strings is something that's needed to keep the run-time libraries happy since that's what they expect.

Comment: So, that means I managed to create a bug that is not even coming up on standart conditions :D I got your point. Now the code works fine. Thank you for your patience and guidence.